# How to filter array with another arrays value

Tags: javascript

**Array One:**

```
[
  { c_id: 6, name: "abc" }, 
  { c_id: 7, name: "xyz" }, 
  { c_id: 8, name: "abc12" }, 
  { c_id: 9, name: "xyz56" }, 
  { c_id: 10, name: "abc456" }
]
```

**Array Two:**

```
[
  { s_id: 2, s_cid: 6, s_slot: "1" }, 
  { s_id: 2, s_cid: 6, s_slot: "1" }, 
  { s_id: 2, s_cid: 6, s_slot: "1" },
  { s_id: 2, s_cid: 10, s_slot: "1" }, 
  { s_id: 2, s_cid: 10, s_slot: "1" }
]
```

I want to filter the first array with the second array, by matching `c_id` and `s_cid`.

**Expected Array:**

```
[{
  c_id: 6,
  name: "abc",
  slot: [{
      s_id: 2,
      s_cid: 6,
      s_slot: "1"
    }, {
      s_id: 2,
      s_cid: 6,
      s_slot: "1"
    },
    {
      s_id: 2,
      s_cid: 6,
      s_slot: "1"
    },
  ]
}, {
  c_id: 7,
  name: "xyz"
}, {
  c_id: 8,
  name: "abc12",
  slot: []
}, {
  c_id: 9,
  name: "xyz56",
  slot: [{
    s_id: 2,
    s_cid: 10,
    s_slot: "1"
  }, {
    s_id: 2,
    s_cid: 10,
    s_slot: "1"
  }]
}, {
  c_id: 10,
  name: "abc456"
}]
```

**Code:**

```
let arr = [];

arr = arr1.filter((el) => { 
    return el.slot = arr2.filter((el2)=> { 
        return el. c_id == el2.s_cid 
    }) 
})
```

What am I doing wrong in this code?

---

**Snippet:**

```js
const arr1 = [{
    c_id: 6,
    name: "abc"
  }, {
    c_id: 7,
    name: "xyz"
  }, {
    c_id: 8,
    name: "abc12"
  }, {
    c_id: 9,
    name: "xyz56"
  },
  {
    c_id: 10,
    name: "abc456"
  }
]

const arr2 = [{
    s_id: 2,
    s_cid: 6,
    s_slot: "1"
  }, {
    s_id: 2,
    s_cid: 6,
    s_slot: "1"
  }, {
    s_id: 2,
    s_cid: 6,
    s_slot: "1"
  },
  {
    s_id: 2,
    s_cid: 10,
    s_slot: "1"
  }, {
    s_id: 2,
    s_cid: 10,
    s_slot: "1"
  }
]

let arr = [];
arr = arr1.filter((el) => {
  return el.slot = arr2.filter((el2) => {
    return el.c_id == el2.s_cid
  })
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: quick one: arr1 doesn't have `slot` property

Comment: I want to create slot array with matching el. c_id == el2.s_cid

Comment: In your expected output, the `c_id` and `s_cid` don't match for the object with a `c_id` of `9` did you mean to do this?

Comment: It returns what you said it should, in what way is this code not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work: First replicate arr1 and loop through its' items. For each item filter arr2 with suiting criteria.

```js
const arr1 = [
  {c_id: 6,name:"abc"},
  {c_id: 7,name:"xyz"},
  {c_id: 8,name:"abc12"},
  {c_id: 9,name:"xyz56"}, 
  {c_id: 10,name:"abc456"}
];
const arr2 = [
  {s_id: 2,s_cid: 6,s_slot:"1"},
  {s_id: 2,s_cid: 6,s_slot:"1"},
  {s_id: 2,s_cid: 6,s_slot:"1"}, 
  {s_id: 2,s_cid: 10,s_slot:"1"},
  {s_id: 2,s_cid: 10,s_slot:"1"}
];

let result = [...arr1];
result.map(x => {
  x['slot'] = arr2.filter(y => {
    return y.s_cid === x.c_id;
  })
});
console.log(result)
```

@gbalduzzi 's suggestion, less "expensive" one:

```js
    const arr1 = [
      {c_id: 6,name:"abc"},
      {c_id: 7,name:"xyz"},
      {c_id: 8,name:"abc12"},
      {c_id: 9,name:"xyz56"}, 
      {c_id: 10,name:"abc456"}
    ];
    const arr2 = [
      {s_id: 2,s_cid: 6,s_slot:"1"},
      {s_id: 2,s_cid: 6,s_slot:"1"},
      {s_id: 2,s_cid: 6,s_slot:"1"}, 
      {s_id: 2,s_cid: 10,s_slot:"1"},
      {s_id: 2,s_cid: 10,s_slot:"1"}
    ];
    
    let groups = {};
    arr2.map(x => {
      const existing = groups[x.s_cid] ? groups[x.s_cid] : [];
      groups[x.s_cid] = [...existing, x]
    });
    
    arr1.map(x => {
      x['slot'] = groups[x.c_id]
    });
    
    // arr1 is the result
    console.log(arr1)
```

Comment: This solution has increased space complexity and is not most optimal. Why not use `.map`?

Comment: Take a gander at mine. :D

Comment: Yes, if they need this operation to be reusable, I would also suggest extracting it to a function, but I doubt it. Everything else stays the same :)

Comment: This is a very nice solution and it works fine. Just be careful to use this code with very large arrays because the second array is looped for every single item in the first array, making it O(n*m)

Comment: @gbalduzzi You are 100% right, but I don't see a simpler solution to this problem. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Yes: you should loop once on the second array and group the items by `s_cid`, then you map the first array to the corresponding group.

Answer (score 2):

You should not filter Array1. Instead you should use map method to create a new array with Array1 to return slot property on each item.

```js
let arr = [];
arr = arr1.map(el=>{
    el.slot = arr2.filter(el2=> { return el.c_id == el2.s_cid;})
    return el;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to do it using `Array.filter` only.

Currently, the first array does not contain `slot` attribute so the process to put filtered second array to `slot` will be needed.

That can be done using `Array.map`.

```js
const arr1 = [{c_id: 6,name:"abc"},{c_id: 7,name:"xyz"},{c_id: 8,name:"abc12"},{c_id: 9,name:"xyz56"}, 
 {c_id: 10,name:"abc456"}];

const arr2 =  [{s_id: 2,s_cid: 6,s_slot:"1"},{s_id: 2,s_cid: 6,s_slot:"1"},{s_id: 2,s_cid: 6,s_slot:"1"}, 
  {s_id: 2,s_cid: 10,s_slot:"1"},{s_id: 2,s_cid: 10,s_slot:"1"}];

const result = arr1.map(({ c_id, name }) => ({
  c_id,
  name,
  slot: arr2.filter(({ s_cid }) => c_id === s_cid)
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution and it works fine. Just be careful to use this code with very large arrays because the second array is looped for every single item in the first array, making it `O(n*m)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a1 = [
  { c_id: 6, name:"abc" },
  { c_id: 7, name:"xyz" },
  { c_id: 8, name:"abc12" },
  { c_id: 9, name:"xyz56" }, 
  { c_id: 10, name:"abc456" },
];

const a2 = [
  { s_id: 2, s_cid: 6, s_slot:"1" },
  { s_id: 2, s_cid: 6, s_slot:"1" },
  { s_id: 2, s_cid: 6, s_slot:"1" }, 
  { s_id: 2, s_cid: 10, s_slot:"1" },
  { s_id: 2, s_cid: 10, s_slot:"1" },
];

const slotArrays = (a, b) => {
  return a.map((item) => {
    item.slot = b.filter((x) => x.s_cid === item.c_id);
    return item;
  });
};

console.log(slotArrays(a1, a2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take another approach with just two loops and collect all slots an in object with `slot` as key and map the first array with the assigned slot or an empty array.

```js
const
    data1 = [{ c_id: 6, name: "abc" }, { c_id: 7, name: "xyz" }, { c_id: 8, name: "abc12" }, { c_id: 9, name: "xyz56" }, { c_id: 10, name: "abc456" }],
    data2 = [{ s_id: 2, s_cid: 6, s_slot: "1" }, { s_id: 2, s_cid: 6, s_slot: "1" }, { s_id: 2, s_cid: 6, s_slot: "1" }, { s_id: 2, s_cid: 10, s_slot: "1" }, { s_id: 2, s_cid: 10, s_slot: "1" }],
    slots = data2.reduce((s, o) => ((s[o.s_cid] = s[o.s_cid] || []).push(o), s), {}),
    result = data1.map(o => ({ ...o, slot: slots[o.c_id] || []}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```